# How to write a no-op UPDATE query?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Suppose we have a simple update query:

```
UPDATE foo
SET
  bar=$1
WHERE id=$2
```

where `bar=$1` is generated based on user's input and it might be null, e.g.

```
UPDATE foo
SET
  ${assignmentList}
WHERE id=$2
```

How do I make this update operation into a no-op in case `assignmentList` variable is empty?

I have tried using `1=1`, i.e.

```
UPDATE foo
SET
  1=1
WHERE id=$2
```

but this gives a syntax error.

Comment: `WHERE id=$2 AND (${assignmentList}) IS NOT NULL`. Or `WHERE id=$2 AND LENGTH('${assignmentList}')>0`. Or something similar...

Comment: I cannot understand why you cannot to check `${assignmentList}` on the application level, and do not execute the query at all when assignmentList it is empty.

Comment: Context: https://github.com/gajus/slonik/issues/46 @Akina I think that the best API is for the generator to throw an error if empty assignment list is provided and make the user guard to make sure that does not happen/ let him not to execute the query. I was checking if there is a generic no-op pattern, though.

Comment: I could do `UPDATE foo SET id=id WHERE id=$2` or any other known column, but that would actually perform an update of the row.

Comment: Can you add conditions in the where clause? If so, add `AND True=False`. By definition of UPDATE clause, in the SET part, the first item (left of =) must be a column name.

Comment: Please confirm that you assemble that variable in a way in cannot be something like `col = 1; DROP DATABASE this;--`

Answer (score 2):

It is only slightly more code to skip the `UPDATE` if there is nothing to do.  And the code is much cleaner.  And less kludgy.

Answer (score 0):

While Rick's answer addresses the root cause here, I would like to answer the more general question "How to write a no-op UPDATE query?"

You can write an UPDATE that does not update any row by providing a WHERE clause that is never true.

```
UPDATE foo
SET bar = 'value'
WHERE 1 <> 1
;
```

Comment: I don't see that it's possible in Postgres. I have a "reasonable" requirement for doing so; I want an update trigger to fire on a few thousand rows and do what it needs to do. So, I want a no-op update where I don't specify any more info just so that it causes the trigger to fire. I'll just workaround... maybe like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53403464/postgres-triggers-and-no-op-updates